# Rigid body initial velocity/rotation?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Is there a way to specify a rigid body's initial velocity or rotation?

Comment: An initial velocity in what? The game engine? The particle system? One of the simulations? Can you add more information to your question? Most questions should be about a paragraph or two long.

Comment: Do you mean angular velocity instead of rotation? Because the initial rotation is the one you set in object mode.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. Let's say I have a cube I want to have shoot sideways at 3 m/s and rotating on its z-axis at 10 degrees per second. Once the simulation starts, it will move sideways and rotate, but also downward because gravity is affecting it.